# Does it exists compatibility SPRINGDOC with AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I wanted to know if there exists a compatibility springdoc with aws lambda like how SPRINGFOX was working perfect.
I couldn`t find anywhere a response to this.
I tried multiple versions when hosting springdoc to aws but what i get is 404 not found, when on localhost works perfectly.

PS: I need springdoc because we move to native and springfox is not compatible with native.

Thanks.

Multiple versions of springdoc, expecting to see the path and result from springdoc.